# White Space at the bottom of a tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

I have a viewcontroller with a tableview inside it. At the bottom of the tableview there is some white space that I want to get rid of and be replaced by my background colour.

I have added and customised the tableview programatically so I am looking for a programatic answer, as I did not use storyboard much for this. (I had only used it to setup my TabBarController and link it to navigation and view-controllers.)

[image: Picture of my tableview and the white space underneath it]

Below is the some of the code I used to configure the tableview.

```
  private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView.register(ProfileTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell.identifier)
    tableView.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor
    return tableView
}()


override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    tableView.frame = view.bounds
}
```

Im sure the answer is probably just a single line of code, but I couldn't find one that worked. Thanks in advance!

***EDIT
I have found a solution, but I still think there is a better way to solve this problem. The code below sets a UIView as the background of the tableview, then changes the colour of the UIView.

```
private let tableView: UITableView = {
    let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .plain)
    tableView.register(ProfileTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ProfileTableViewCell.identifier)
    let backgroundView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0,
                                              y: 0,
                                              width: tableView.bounds.size.width,
                                              height: tableView.bounds.size.height))
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor
    tableView.backgroundView = backgroundView
    return tableView
}()
```

Answer (score 0):

The default color of the containing view controller is showing, since the table is short. Try setting the view controller's view's background color in `viewDidLoad`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() { 
  super.viewDidLoad();
  view.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work, but thanks for the reply.

Comment: The tableView is itself a `UIView` subclass. Also try `tableView.backgroundColor = Constants.backgroundColor`